# Facebook send button WITHOUT a link

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I would like to use the [Facebook send Button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/send-button) to trigger the same frame where you can choose friends and a message ...

But without this anoying URL and image preview of a website...

My real objective is to send to all the friends the user want an ID (it's the id of the room for socket.io ...)

So How can I customise the message string ? 
And how can I get rid of the link obligation ?

And how to do it without an app_id ?

**Code:**

```
      <!-- Load Facebook SDK for JavaScript -->
      <div id="fb-root"></div>
      <script>
        (function(d, s, id) {
          var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
          if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
          js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
          js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5";
          fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

      <!-- Your send button code -->
      <div class="fb-send" 
        data-href="https://www.google.fr/webhp?hl=fr" 
        data-layout="button_count">
      </div>
```

Comment: You can't customize the message. The user have to write it.